# how do round int with Ceiling

Tags: c#, rounding

how do i convert value and round off int values?

Example:

```
int x = 121;
int y = Math.Ceiling(x/8);
```

Get Error:

Cannot implicitly convert type `double` to `int`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: (int)Math.Ceiling(x/8);Actually u are assigning flot value to int.so you should cast it to int

Comment: Get this error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Ceiling(double)' and 'System.Math.Ceiling(decimal)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can try using this:-

```
 int x = 121;
 int y = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)x/8);
```

Comment: May want to use `x/8m` to remove ambiguous call to `Math.Ceiling`

Comment: Get this error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Ceiling(double)' and 'System.Math.Ceiling(decimal)

Comment: Try this:- int y = (int)x/8m; or int y = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)x/8);

Comment: This is ridiculous... Obviously I want an integer, I'm using a ceil function - why is the go-to return a decimal?

Answer (score 6):

No need to move to floating point math, just do this:

```
y = (x+7) / 8
```

`(a + b - 1) / b` rounded down equals `a / b` rounded up.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you are assigning `float` value to `int`.So you should cast it to int before assinging

```
int y = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)x/8);
```

Comment: Get this error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Ceiling(double)' and 'System.Math.Ceiling(decimal)

Answer (score -1):

Use an explicit cast

```
int y=(int)Math.Ceiling(x/8);
```

Comment: Get this error: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Math.Ceiling(double)' and 'System.Math.Ceiling(decimal)